# I am looking for title of alien visitors who share technology with us

Tags: story-identification

Aliens came to earth and shared technology with us. One piece of this technology was a teleport system. There were teleport stations set up in every town. People were eventually keen on using them.

Eventually it was learned that there was a delay in the time it took to teleport and it was discovered that all the females were being made sterile. This was the alien's way of conquering the earth and wiping us all out.

I know the series is not "V".

Comment: Book, movie, Tv-series, short story ? What are you looking for?

Comment: I am assuming TV series but I am not going to edit as it may not be.

Comment: All but the sterilization part fits to earth: final conflict... do you remember anything more? even seemingly unimportant details might help

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like the Stargate episode "[2010](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/2010_(episode))". The SG1 team make contact with an advanced civilisation known as the Aschen. The episode features both ubiquitous teleportation and female sterilisation

[image]

Comment: My first thought as well. The teleportation is not what causes the sterilisation, though, if I recall correctly. That is done through immunisations given to humans by the Aschen, which proof us against cancer and other illnesses, while extending our lifespans. The theory is that no one would suspect that something that allows them to live an extra hundred years would wipe out their species. The Aschen use this tactic on multiple worlds.

Comment: @jamessheridan - You're not wrong. The idea of the aliens using the transporter as a way of abducting people sounds like outer limits or similar

Comment: The Aschen do use the transporter to kill General Hammond.

Comment: @Richard yes that is also what the puppeteers do with the transport system in larry niven books.

Comment: Aliens abducting people in teleport is also featured in the Hyperion cantos, although without sterilization.

Comment: Thanks. I did watch the stargate series but cannot recall my memory as part of this series but I will check it out again.